# Router Navigate Without Call To Server -- Reuse Component?

Tags: angular, location, command-line-interface, router

I have three dependent drop-down lists, which the user will be clicking on to navigate through different areas, and as user clicks through them, I want the router to update, but without reloading the page.

I tried location.replaceState(), but I can't create a UrlTree with that, because location doesn't update router.

I got the path set up this way

```
{
      path: '/area/ma/:id',
      component: SomeComponent
}
```

In the drop down, `(click)` calls `router.navigate()` and sets up the url to the above. Now that `SomeComponent` is initialized, it always calls a service that contacts the server to get the area data on `ngOnInit()` is there a way to prevent that from happening?

`some.component.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getArea();
}

getArea(): void {
    this.metadataService.getMeta()
        .subscribe(meta => {
            this.area= meta;
        });
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "without reloading the page"? I think by default, Angular uses pushState so the page shouldn't reload...

Comment: It will be easier to answer if you add some code to your question

Comment: Why don't you use router.navigate() ? This should be handled by angular and not send a request to the server.

Comment: So whenever a component loads, it sends a request to the server to fetch location data. Router.navigate() reloads the page making the component load again, which ngOnInit makes a call to the server.